# jquery ui tabs aren't working as intended

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

ive created the following code. it shows the tabs i want but the content on the page doesnt change when i click a tab. the content for all the tabs is shown on the same page. when i click a tab the link goes in the address bar in the browser. 
any ideas how to stop this link happening and to get the content separated into tabs?
    
    
    
        
        Sonachan - Bar

```
    <link href="/scripts/jui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="admin-tabs" class="col">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#admin-tabs-1"><span>Add an Item</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#admin-tabs-2"><span>Change an Item</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#admin-tabs-3"><span>Add a Category</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#admin-tabs-4"><span>Change a Category</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="admin-page">
            <?php //add an item ?>
            <div id="admin-tabs-1">

                <div class="admin-heading">Add an item</div>
                <form id="additemform">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Select a category:
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <select>
                                    <?php foreach (Category::model()->findAll() as $category): ?>
                                        <option id="cat-<?php echo $category->id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Product name:
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Product price:
                            </td>
                            <td id="poundsign">£</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input id="price-pounds"></input>
                                .
                                <input id="price-pence" maxlength="2"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Create!"></input></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="admin-tabs-2">
                content of tab 2
            </div>
            <div id="admin-tabs-3">
                content of tab 3
            </div>
            <div id="admin-tabs-4">
                content of tab 4
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

and this is my jquery :

```
$(function() {
$("#admin-tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Comment: Can we see the `head` of your HTML document? Are you including CSS and JavaScript files for jQueryUI? Do you have any errors on the page?

Comment: It looks like you're using Yii, in which case, using the CJuiTabs plugin http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiTabs might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin jQuery UI Tabs expects the panels (tab content) to be **within the container you apply the .tabs() on**, which is not the case with your markup.

To find your panels (`#admin-tabs-1`, `#admin-tabs-2`, ...), the plugin will search into the container `#admin-tabs` and from your markup it does not find any of them as they are outside the container.

You have:

```
<div#admin-tabs>
    <ul>
        <li #admin-tabs-1>
        <li #admin-tabs-2>
        <li #admin-tabs-3>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div#admin-tabs-1>
    <div#admin-tabs-2>
    <div#admin-tabs-3>
</div>
```

The plugin expects:

```
<div#admin-tabs>
    <ul>
        <li #admin-tabs-1>
        <li #admin-tabs-2>
        <li #admin-tabs-3>
    </ul>
    <div#admin-tabs-1>
    <div#admin-tabs-2>
    <div#admin-tabs-3>
</div>
```

Move your panels next to the `<ul>`.

Also make sure you linked the CSS stylesheets that comes along with the jQuery UI library.

Your markup: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/u23z5/)

Expected markup: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8XQ6w/)

Comment: added in the head of the page. the opening head tag is just before that first link. ive got the css and javascript files linked and there are no errors on the page. Im using netbeans IDE not Yii framework.

Comment: I have reformulated my answer. You have to change your markup a little in order for the plugin to work as expected.